# Disable STARTTLS on Qmail for outgoing messages

Tags: tls, email

I've a Plesk 10.5 server with QMAIL as MTA.

We are facing issues when sending e-mail to certain domains and I would like to know if you guys know how to disable STARTTLS when sending e-mail through QMAIL.

I took a look on xinetd files and I could not find anything forcing TLS (FORCE_TLS=1).

Logs from TCPDUMP:

> TCP>[Y-SRC] [X-SRC] > SMTP SYN TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > SYN ACK
>   TCP>[Y-SRC] [X-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > 220 mail.domain.tld ESMTP Postfix TCP>[Y-SRC]
>   [X-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[Y-SRC] [X-DST] > EHLO mail.mydomain.tld TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] >
>   ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > 250 mail.domain.tld
>            250 PIPELINING
>            250 SIZE 204800000
>            250 VRFY
>            250 ETRN
>            250 STARTTLS
>            250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>            250 8BITMIME
>            250 DSN
>
> SMTP>[Y-SRC] [X-DST] > STARTTLS TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>
> SMTP>[Y-SRC] [X-DST] > Client Hello TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
>   TCP>[Y-SRC] [X-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[Y-SRC] [X-DST] > Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec,
>   Encrypted Handshake Message TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > Change Cipher Spec TCP>[Y-SRC] [X-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > Encrypted Handshake Message
>   TCP>[Y-SRC] [X-SRC] > ACK
>
> SMTP>[Y-SRC] [X-DST] > Application Data, Application Data TCP>[X-DST]
>   [Y-SRC] > ACK TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > FIN ACK
>
> SMTP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > Encrypted Alert TCP>[X-DST] [Y-SRC] > RST

Comment: Why do you not want STARTTLS?

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on how Qmail was configured with TLS/SSL support I think. Check your `man qmail-remote` for supported debug options and controls.

According to [this version](http://inoa.net/qmail-tls/qmail-remote.txt) you can create a control file `notlshosts/<FQDN>` to suppress the upgrade to TLS for certain destinations i.e. the host/domain you're trying to debug:

```
        notlshosts/<FQDN> 
        qmail-remote  will  not  try TLS on servers for which
        this  file  exists  (<FQDN>  is  the  fully-qualified
        domain  name  of  the  server).  (tlshosts/<FQDN>.pem
        takes precedence over this file however).
```